# How to query rows between specific date range in MySQL efficiently?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with a certain column say `created_time` with datatype as `datetime`. It is also one of the **primary key** on that table.

Now when I try to query a date range `created_time BETWEEN :startTime AND :endTime` , it ends up looking through the entire table as I can see from the **execution plan**.

Now, there is another primary key column `sensor_time` with data type as `INT` which stores the time in **unix** format. When I use the range in this, it only looks through the database for a small subsection.

Please someone explain me why the range does not work efficiently with the `datetime` type even though it is a primary key.

Comment: date_time is not a data type

Comment: Sorry, I meant `datetime`. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is also one of the primary key on that table.

Uh.  This is not possible. A primary key is a set of columns with the following characteristics:

- The values are never `NULL`.
- The combination of the column(s) in a given row are always unique.
- **There is only one primary key**.

You probably have a *composite* primary key, composed of multiple columns.  In that case, `datetime` filters would only be used for a query with this restriction:

```
where created_time between ? and ?
```

when `created_time` is the FIRST column in the primary key.  Otherwise, the preceding columns need equality comparisons.

It sounds like you want a second column on `datetime` with that as the first column in the index (if there are multiple columns).

Comment: My primary goal is to query between a specified range of dates without having to go for a full table lookup. Is it achievable in my case ?? Sorry, I didn't get the last paragraph.

Comment: @VikrantPradhan . . . Create a secondary index on `created_time`.